# why i am getting 404 error when i am testing my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

i am using jest to test my application but when I add more and more code to test, i get more errors to previous codes.

I have this code to test in test

```
const {Genre} = require('../../models/genre')

describe('GET /:id', ()=>{
        it('should return genre with given id', async ()=>{
            const genre = new Genre({ name: "Genre1 "});
            await genre.save();
            console.log(genre._id)
            const res = await request(server).get('/api/genres/' + genre._id);

            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('name', genre.name)
        })
    });
```

this one is in genres.js

```
router.get('/:id', validateObjectId  ,async (req, res) => {
  const genre = await Genre.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!genre) return res.status(404).send('The genre with the given ID was not found.');

  res.send(genre);
});
```

and i am getting error:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 200
    Received: 404

      32 |             const res = await request(server).get('/api/genres/' + genre._id);
      33 | 
    > 34 |             expect(res.status).toBe(200);
         |                                ^
      35 |             expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('name', genre.name)
      36 |         })
      37 |         it('should return 404 if invalid id is passed', async ()=>{
```

is there any solution to fix this? 
when i run only genres.test.js file it works fine but when i want to test all my project it gets error

Comment: Are you sure the `id` is being populated correctly in the test code?

Comment: Yes, I logged id in the console and it was correct

Comment: This endpoint works testing with something like postman?

Comment: yes it works in postman

Comment: You've logged in `generes.js` to verify things are happening as expected?